# I renamed magisk.apk to magisk.zip using fastboot then flashed to /boot, I am on a bootloop

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking, lenovo

I have a Lenovo TB125FU device, that is the "technical name" for the Lenovo Tab M10 Plus 3rd Gen. I was trying to root it. I already have unlocked bootloader and had PixelExperience Plus by Ponces ROM.

I accidentally flashed `magisk.zip` instead of `magisk.img` to `/boot` using `fastboot flash boot magisk.zip`. I tried to enter both recovery mode, recovery mode LRM (Lenovo recovery mode) and failed. First recovery mode was I guess non-existent because of the Android 10 fastbootd change, however I was able to boot into LRM, but tried `fastboot reboot fastboot` from just fastboot, not fastbootd. That didn't change the bootloop, but didn't let me be able to go back into bootloader.

So just fastboot, I suppose that the bootloop after the command is the system trying to go to fastbootd. I tried the hard reset/shutdown mode but didn't work. After doing it, I tried once again rebooting to LRM but it didn't work. The black screen that appears when it's mid bootloop just stays there longer.

I tried adb and fastboot commands during that period but nothing happened. I tried volume down which is what I would use to reboot to bootloader from LRM but nothing happened. `fastboot devices` command outputted nothing.

I do not know how to fix it and orange state is gone, it doesn't appear anymore when rebooting, it just shows Lenovo and Powered by Android.

I need help please. I'm certain that it's just a soft brick but I have no idea of how to fix it. I don't care about data. I just want a functional system again.

Comment: so why you don't flash boot.img or magisk.img afterwards from just fastboot not fastbootd